# Loop through cells and display values in message box using infinite loop

Tags: vba

I am writing a piece of code that loops through all values in a column (till it hits an empty row) and adds values that contain "Wooden" to a range to be displayed at the end in a message box.

In the image linked [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg0RM.png), it will start from A2 and go down each row, check the value in column C for that roller coaster and if C is wooden, add the value in A to a range to be displayed at the end.

Code:

```
 Sub checktype()
 Dim wooden As Range
 Range("A2").Select
 Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
     If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Wood" Then
         If wooden Is Nothing Then
             Set wooden = ActiveCell
         Else
             Set wooden = Union(wooden, ActiveCell)
         End If
     End If
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
 Loop
 MsgBox wooden
 End Sub
```

However, the code only returns 'Grand National'- the first entry that has wooden in column C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an array to process faster, and as I think you want the string values, you don't need to union the ranges, but instead, concatenate the values of the qualifying cells. Using an array and avoiding `.Select` is a lot faster.
Gathering qualifying ranges with Union, and then joining the values is a little more complex as the union range may not contain continuous ranges you can easily index, transpose and join into a string.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub checktype()
    Dim wooden As String, loopRange As Range, arr(), i As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<== change to your sheet
        Set loopRange = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
        Set loopRange = loopRange.Resize(loopRange.Rows.Count, 3)

        If loopRange.Count = 1 Then
            ReDim arr(1, 1): arr(1, 1) = .Range("A2").Value
        Else
            arr = loopRange.Value
        End If

        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            If arr(i, 3) = "Wood" Then
                wooden = wooden & Chr$(32) & arr(i, 1)
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Msgbox wooden
End Sub
```

Comment: However, do you know what was wrong with the previous code ? It might not be the most efficient way of doing this, but I am trying to use these exercises to learn VBA.

Comment: I hinted it at it in the top of my answer.  Your syntax is wrong. Wth union you are gathering potentially discontinuous ranges  which can't be used to generate an array with wooden.Value . That array, if continuous would also be 2dimensional which would mean you need to slice the 1st column out, likely transpose it and then use Join, or loop it to join  each cell value together into a string. The alternative with what you have is to loop all the  cells within the .Areas of your Union object and concatenate the .Value s together.

Comment: Did that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that made perfect sense! Thanks a lot! It's working now